# Error Changing Directory on Python Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, directory

Very new to python here and I have referenced several other questions on stack overflow, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong here. I have tried the following:

```
os.chdir('/home/documents/Netflix Project/Cleaned Data')

os.chdir("/home/luke/documents/Netflix Project/Cleaned Data")
```

Every time I get the same error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Home/luke/Documents/Netflix Project/Cleaned Data'
```

Am I using incorrect syntax to call the directory? I have been basing it off the following:

```
>>> os.getcwd()
'/home'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths are case-sensitive. Are you sure you're not using `Home` instead of `home`? The traceback looks like you are.